# Problem with finding solutions to polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the best method to find the solutions to this equation?

$x^3(x^2+2)=-297$

I have obtained the solution from the back of the book but have no idea as to the method to get the solution. Is it merely a matter of plugging in numbers?

Comment: If you were to assume that $x$ is an integer, then you can look at the factorization of $297=3^3\cdot 11$ and use this to reach your conclusion that $x=-3$ is one solution.

Comment: If you do *not* make the assumption that $x$ must be an integer, then you'll find there are potentially *five different* complex number solutions to the equation.  In some special cases you could find them explicitly, however there is no guarantee you can for fifth degree or higher polynomials.

Comment: Note also that because $x^5$ and $2x^3$ are strictly increasing functions of $x$ (for $x\in \mathbb R$) so is their sum, and it is easy to deduce from this that there will be precisely one real solution. $-4^5=-1024$ and the left-hand side is zero for $x=0$ so the solution will be between $-4$ and $0$. Because the equation has integer coefficients, and the leading coefficient is $1$, any rational solution will be an integer. Any integer solution will be odd. So it is easy to constrain the search space.

Comment: You might want to look at the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) if you don't know it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$x^3(x^2+2)=-297$$
or
$$x^3(x^2+2)=(-3)^3(11)$$
$$x^3(x^2+2)=(-3)^3((-3)^2+2)$$

Comment: you're right. That was the answer on the back of the book. But as for the method to find that, you just recognise that -297 can be factored by 11 and -27 or 11 and $-3^3$? Is this just a matter of experience with such problems that cradle to see the factors of large numbers and plug-in the solution accordingly?

Comment: I think that the idea of ​​this question is to focus on factoring

Comment: yeah, i guess I'll get better at seeing such factoring patterns with time and experience. Thanks for the feedback!